# In PHP, find an existing file using a regex pattern for the file name

Tags: php, regex, filenames

I'm aware of the [glob function](http://php.net/glob). However, I am needing to match a regex pattern. Say I have the following directory of files:

```
/assets
  |- logo-abd6d458.png
  |- logo-big-bd7543cd.png
  |- another-ab87dbf0.css
  +- something-784b52ac.png
```

I need a PHP function that should return a filename of an existing file in this directory when I only know the *start of the file name* and the *extension*. For example:

```
function asset_name($start, $extension) {
  // Some magic here
}
```

`asset_name('logo', 'png');` should return `"logo-abd6d458.png"`, but it should not return `"logo-big-bd7543cd.png"`.

`asset_name('logo-big', 'png');` should return `"logo-big-bd7543cd.png"`.

Can anyone figure out the "magic" for this function? I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** The assets directory is a copy of another directory, however each of the files are renamed to include a hyphen and then an eight-character unique hash at the end of the file name (for cache-busting). So an original file `logo.png` will be renamed to `logo-abd6d458.png`. Another file such as `logo-big.something.else.here.png` would become `logo-big.something.else.here-dcba4321.png` and I would then use `asset_name('logo-big.something.else.here', 'png');`.

When calling the function I would always be using the whole original filename for $start and the extension for $extension.

Comment: Here is your magic: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php

Comment: Use `scandir` and then use `preg_match` on each element of the returned array.

Comment: @Rizier123 That does globbing, not regexp.

Comment: I don't understand your example. You say it should match the beginning of the filename and the extension. Why doesn't `logo-big-bd7543cd.png` match? It starts with `logo` and ends with the `png` extension.

Comment: Is there another rule that the middle can't contain any `-` characters? Any other restrictions?

Comment: When you have only `logo-abd6d458.png` matches. Try to split firstly by `$start` , then splite the rest of your filename by `-` and if it length is greather than 1 dont return it. Else split by `.` and compare `$extension` with the 2nd element. For first matches you can do this regex : `\s\+\-\s(.+\..+)`. The group 1 for first match (`+- logo-abd6d458.png`) is `logo-abd6d458.png`

Comment: @Barmar I just realized your point with the matching. I updated the question to further explain.

Comment: *cough* [the top comment in the glob manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#88250) explains that you can do pattern matching with `glob`, and also gives examples if you need to do pattern matching beyond what it is capable of *coughcough*

Comment: yes, something like this: `logo-[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9].png` or `logo-[^-][^-][^-][^-][^-][^-][^-][^-].png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it based on your exemples.

I'm assuming that your checksum is of fixed length so you can just remove the (10+length of extension)th last chars of the filename and make the comparison.

```
<?php

function asset_name($start, $ext)
{
    $dir = 'assets';
    $files = glob($dir.'/*.'.$ext);

    $suffixLength = -9 - strlen($ext) - 1;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = substr($file, strlen($dir)+1, $suffixLength);
        if ($name === $start) {
            return $file;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception('file not found');
}

$file = asset_name('logo', 'png');
```

Comment: That's a beauty. The hash is fixed to 8 characters, so it looks like this will work for me. Thank you!